# Parent grid is not refreshing in firefox browser when using this method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firefox

I am using this method for refreshing a parent grid when opening from pop-up (child).....

but this script is not working in firefox browser....any reason for this?

```
var myWindow = window.open(ROOT +'Documents/FileUpload, '_blank', 'height=430px, width=600px,left=450px,top=240px,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
            myWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){        
            $("#pegGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```